# Subselect on date

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

In an Access database there are two tables.

Table one containing Articles and table two contains Prices.

So Articles is the description of all articles and the prices
table just contains an article number, a date date and a price.
If a prices changes, there will be added a new row to prices.

The prices have a date from which on that price shall be used.

Now I want to get the prices that were valid on 01. Oct 2012.
I used my query on current prices and added `and prsdat<#02/10/2012#`
to the subselect in the query.

Here is what I already have:

```
SELECT 
    Articles.ARTNR, 
    Articles.TXT, 
    Articles.ACTIVE, 
    Prices.PRICE, 
    Prices.PRSGR, 
    Prices.PRSDAT
FROM 
    Articles INNER JOIN Prices ON Articles.ARTNR = Prices.ARTNR
WHERE 
    (((Articles.ACTIVE)="Y") AND 
    ((Prices.PRSGR)=0) AND 
    ((Prices.PRSDAT)=
        (SELECT 
            max(prsdat)  
        FROM 
            Prices as art 
        WHERE 
            art.artnr = Prices.artnr and prsdat<#02/10/2012#)))
ORDER BY 
    Articles.ARTNR;
```

Now the select returns articles that I did not see with this select
I used before, having just added `and prsdat<#01/10/2012#`.
The result is now 430 articles, before I just had about 260.

The prices returned are older, but I'm not sure about the date format.
In the table I see DD.MM.YYYY, and in the query i shall use MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY?

What is the correct form of this select?

Comment: What is the meaning of `(Prices.PRSGR)=0` ? You should at least duplicate that clause in the subquery.

Comment: If you run the subquery by itself, what does it return?

Comment: @wildplasser There are pricegroups and I am interested in pricegroup 0.

Comment: @DanBracuk I have deleted the `art.artnr = Prices.artnr`part then duplicated the `PrsGr=0` part from the outer select and it returns a single date then. seems to be correct for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    a.ARTNR
    , a.TXT
    , a.ACTIVE -- dubious, since it is constant
    , p.PRICE
    , p.PRSGR  -- dubious, since it is constant
    , p.PRSDAT
FROM Articles a
INNER JOIN Prices p ON a.ARTNR = p.ARTNR
WHERE a.ACTIVE = 'Y' 
  AND p.PRSGR = 0 
  AND p.prsdat < #02/10/2012#
  AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *   
      FROM Prices nx 
      WHERE nx.ARTNR = p.ARTNR
        AND nx.PRSGR = 0
        AND nx.prsdat < #02/10/2012#
        AND nx.prsdat > p.prsdat
          )
ORDER BY 
    Articles.ARTNR
   ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But the resultset is empty with that.

Comment: Maybe I made an error, or maybe there *are no records* satisfying your conditions. I don't know about the date-literal format `#02/10/2012#`, it looks very suspicious to me, Maybe it accepts an iso-date, like `2013-03-16` ?

Comment: No error, your query results in exactly what it should. Don't know what was wrong earlier. Thank you very much!